# lwuit change language and apply it

Tags: internationalization, lwuit, codenameone

I have a form to change language of my j2me application. This application is created by codenameone.

I create a class and I write all my words into it in 2 language English and Farsi. I change the language with this code:

```
UIManager.getInstance().setResourceBundle(new CommonSettings().getFarsi());
```

How can I apply this language to all components of this form lively or without exit from this form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recreate the form. The GUI builder can do this automatically for you if you invoke the method `reloadForm()` in the state machine.

Comment: I didn't use UIbuilder class anyway for some reason, so I can't use this method. all of my classes derived from "com.codenameone.ui.form".

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Recreate your form. If you have hand coded createMyForm() method then just call it again and show that form without a transition.

Comment: I did it as you said, I recreated form on back command. Thanks.